# Ajax redirect to URL after success

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect

I have a problem, my function do not redirect after success.
I do not why is no redirect...
If I put ...href after e.preventDefault(); it works sometimes.

```
$('#nadwozie').change(function (e) {
        if (window.confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz zmienić nadwozie/grafikę pojazdu ?')) {
            var url = "raport_zapisanie_danepojazdu.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#FormRaport").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = "raport.php?id=" + <?php echo $raport[0]['id'];?> +"&nadwozie=" + $(this).val();
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    //alert(request.responseText + status + error);
                }
            })
            ;
            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        } else {
            $("#nadwozie").val(previous);
            previous = $(this).val();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe it's triggering the error handler?  I don't know why you are using ajax instead of regular old form submit to `raport_zapisanie_danepojazdu.php` which could then redirect server side to `raport.php`

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace:

```
window.location.href = "raport.php?id=" + <?php echo $raport[0]['id'];?> +"&nadwozie=" + $(this).val();
```

with:

```
window.location.assign("raport.php?id=" + <?php echo $raport[0]['id'];?> +"&nadwozie=" + $(this).val());
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

assign() actually redirects to the given url, whereas href simply returns the url.